# how to get redirected to the exact url in javascript

Tags: javascript

when I’m trying to go to url like this

> $.get("getdetailofselectedcustmor/", function(){

})

in my js code , I’m redirected to 'current url + getdetailofselectedcustmor', but what I’m looking for is just to get redirected to 'localhost:8000/getdetailofselectedcustmor/', how can I  do that?

Comment: Add `/` at the beginning of the passed path?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Django problem, it is a problem with the JS request

make sure you always put `/` before whatever resource path you want to request.

like this

```
$.get("/getdetailofselectedcustmor/", function(...){...})
```